No audio on Asus UX5304VA across multiple distros and audio devices
I'm pretty new to linux but I have some experience, and I've been trying to make this work for the past 3 days. I am on a dual boot setup with MX linux and win11 right now. The problem is, my computer refuses to make any sound come out of it when running Linux (win11 still works). Built-in speakers, speakers through USB and USB-c and bluetooth speakers all do not work. The audio slider moves when sound should be there, but nothing comes out.
I have messed around with pulseaudio and alsa trying to find if anything is muted, but everything is as it should be. I have also tried switching distros (MX linux, Mint debian edition, Manjaro), all of them had the same issue. Changing to a older or newer kernel has no effect.
Other fixes that I've tried and didn't work:
https://github.com/badgers-ua/asus_zenbook_ux5304va_sound
https://www.linux.org/threads/solved-asus-zenbook-15-ux534f-realtek-hd-audio-problem.27384/
Updating BIOS
Running from a live USB
Unmuting everything in alsamixer
Some more info about my setup:
Output of neofetch:

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   palach@MXkanon 
@@@@@@@@@@@@%*+--:------=+*%@@@@@@@@@@@@   -------------- 
@@@@@@@@@#=. .-+#%@@@@@%#*+--=#@@@@@@@@@   OS: MX x86_64 
@@@@@@@+. .=%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*-:+@@@@@@@   Host: Zenbook S 13 UX5304VA_UX5304VA 1.0 
@@@@@*.  *@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%-.*@@@@@   Kernel: 6.9.12-2-liquorix-amd64 
@@@@-  -@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#:  -@@@@   Uptime: 1 hour, 42 mins 
@@@:  -@@@@@@@=.*@@@@@@@@@@@@%-   = :@@@   Packages: 2513 (dpkg) 
@@=  .@@@@@@@@%- :%@@@@@@@@@+   -%@# =@@   Shell: bash 5.2.15 
@%   +@@@@@@@@@@#. =@@@@@@*.  .*@@@@. %@   Resolution: 2880x1800 
@+   *@@@@@@*..*@@+  *@@%-   =@@@@@@- +@   DE: Plasma 5.27.5 
@=   *@@@@%-    -%@@- :=   -%@@@@@@@: +@   WM: KWin 
@+   :@@@=        +@@=   .#@@@@@@@@%  *@   Theme: Breeze [GTK2/3] 
@%    +*.          .:     *@@#: +@@:  @@   Icons: Papirus-Dark [GTK2/3] 
@@+                   :%@- :-    ::  +@@   Terminal: yakuake 
@@@-                  .=@@=         -@@@   CPU: 13th Gen Intel i5-1335U (12) @ 2.501GHz 
@@+.                     .           +@@   GPU: Intel Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] 
%=..:.................::...........:..-%   Memory: 5957MiB / 15612MiB 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

Output of lspci -v  | grep -i audio:

0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)
       Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl

Output of aplay -l:

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
 Subdevices: 0/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 31: HDA Analog Deep Buffer (*) []
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

There are reports of this issue being consistent across this range of laptops from ASUS. Some people say that a kernel upgrade fixed the issue for them, but it didn't for me.
Thank you for any help, I am getting kind of desperate now.
